# jQuery .live mouseover erroring out

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list (UL) that I'm trying to bind a mouseover/mouseenter event on the list item (LI) children using .live() but keep getting the following JavaScript error:

```
Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
```

Here's my code:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>option 1
        <ul>
            <li>sub-option A</li>
            <li>sub-option B</li>
            <li>sub-option C</li>
            <li>sub-option D</li>
            <li>sub-option E</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$("#menu").children().live("mouseover", function(){
    // do something
});
```

The crazy thing is that when I change to the .mouseover() function it works just fine except for the issue with flickering associated with .mouseover() that the .live("mouseover", ...) fixes.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is this a jQuery bug?  Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Comment: are you inserting the list items dynamically ?

Comment: you are missing a `;` at the end of jquery code ... just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector

Which means you can't do `$("#menu").children().live(...)` since `.children()` is a DOM traversal method.

Although a syntax error suggests that the code itself is problematic, i.e. not well formatted. As such the problem lies in code you didn't post.

Finally, I suggest you just use `delegate`:

```
$('#menu').delegate('li', 'mouseover', function(){ ... });
```

Although you should really be doing a static bind unless you need `live` or `delegate` functionality. It's not supposed to fix random flickering issues - you're supposed to debug that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not inserting the list items dynamically to the DOM in my opinion you dont need to use the `.live` as far as the flickering problem you are facing is probably because the `mouseover` bubbles instead if you use `mouseenter` you will be fine ...

```
$("#menu").children().bind("mouseenter",function(){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: This should use `delegate()` on `#menu`.

Comment: the `delegated` version is already given by davin see the answer below thats why im not including it in my answer